# php scraping excat search with quotation marks "batman kill a human"

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I have a little PHP script for scraping google. I wnat to google the exact search "batman kill a human" I pass the param with simple quoation marks "batman kill a human"
and  I can see a correct URL generated.

I call the script with the param '"batman kill a human"', and I get  >Error 400 (Bad Request)

### example

root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# php  ejemplo.php  '"batman kill a human"'

------------- [https://www.google.es/search?q="batman kill a human"]
------------- [

Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1        *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding
  ....
  ...
-------------------------------------------  
  
  if i try to use this url in firefox, https://www.google.es/search?q="batman kill a human" y get a correct answer from google.
  Why i don't get a correct answer when I'm trying it from the php scritp
  
  
  this is the source code.

```
  <?php
   include('simple_html_dom.php');
 
    function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    /*
    This is a file_get_contents replacement function using cURL
    One slight difference is that it uses your browser's idenity
    as it's own when contacting google. 
    */
    $ch = curl_init();
 
    //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

 
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
 
    return $data;
    }


    $busca=$argv[1];
    $cadena="https://www.google.es/search?q=$busca";

    print "\n------------- [$cadena]";
    $data=file_get_contents_curl($cadena);    
    $html = str_get_html($data);


    print "\n------------- [$html]";


    $html->clear(); exit();  
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on `urlencode()`

```
$busca=$argv[1];
```

becomes

```
$busca=urlencode($argv[1]);
```

Which renders as:

> https://www.google.es/search?q=batman+kills+a+human